# Reduce durability to improve performace in db2

Tags: performance, db2, db2-luw

In db2 10.5, is it possible that  transaction commit  does not wait for log IO to finish and return control to the client, like SQL server's delayed durability? 
Is there any way to reduce the number of log IOs when there are large number of serial small transactions?

Comment: If this is a kind of data you're willing to lose, why insert it into the database in the first place? This sounds awfully like an X-Y problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

Db2 LUW has a database configuration parameter called `mincommit`. The value of [mincommit](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000244.html) indicates how many transactions will commit before flushing out the log buffer to disk. This is probably what you are looking for.

From Db2 LUW v10.5 and higher, this parameter is ignored, and the value is only meaningful on versions of Db2 LUW up to v10.1.

For older versions of Db2 LUW, the recommendation is to leave the value at 1. In most cases there is no performance improvement while at the same time introducing risk. Hence, the configuration parameter has been deprecated in version 10.1. My advice: Do not use it even though it still exists.

Comment: I have seen mincommit before but it doesn't exists in DB2 10.5, it is necessary for me to do something like that, Is there another parameter or configuration for this purpose?

Comment: No, as stated, no replacement for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Db2 on Linux/Unit/Windows, at version 11.1 does not currently support lazy commits as offered by some versions of Microsoft SQL-server.

For some kinds of processing, especially large batches, it is often very convenient to use unlogged global temporary tables for intermediate tables. That is the one convenient way to eliminate logging overhead, although the use case is limited to specific scenarios. Such tables (declared global temporary tables,  or created global temporary tables) let you do fast processing without incurring logging overhead, although you have to design your batches (typically your stored procedures) to work with these kinds of tables, including the ability to restart after failures and recover etc.

If you have high frequency discrete OLTP transactions that include both insert AND update (not batch) , you should concentrate on optimising your active-logging configuration. For example to ensure your active logs are on the fastest media, to ensure your Db2 is never waiting for log files, to ensure that the logbufsz is adequate, to ensure that the bufferpool cleaning is optimal etc, to ensure that the size of your transaction-log files is compatible with your RTO and RPO Service-levels.